# Checking whether given series is nonnegative.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a question: is this true that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)\left(\frac{1}{n^{a}}-\frac{1}{n^{b}}\right)^{2}\ge 0$$

For every $a,b \in (0,0.5)$?

Where $a(n)=\sum_{d|n}(-1)^{d+\frac{n}{d}}\cos\left(y\ln\left(\frac{n}{d^{2}}\right)\right)$

I tried to use Abel's summation formula or summation by parts, but i have no idea how to solve this problem.

Also i need some hints how to generally solve that kind of problems (i mean proving that given infinite series is nonnegative).

I will be grateful if someone help me.

Regards.

Comment: What is $y$, here?

Comment: It is a positive real number.

Comment: In that case, it strikes me as exceedingly unlikely that this is true in general. For a method of proving it: take the maximally-bad $y$ to make the first few terms as negative as possible, then bound the size of the remaining terms in terms of that. Working on an explicit bounding now.

Comment: There is one more question. Is it true that: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a(n)\frac{(\ln n)^{2}}{n^x}\ge 0$$ For all $x>0$ ?